# What the hash sign do in the following statement

Tags: c

Can someone explain what the purpose of the **#** sign in this printf statement:

```
printf("%#d\n",15);
```

It seems to be ignored while printing. The output of the statement is:

> 15

Comment: NOP. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: RTFM [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

Comment: NO hard feelings, but I simply cant believe the Q is standing at `+3/-3`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look in the [`printf` documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm). You can find the description for `#` under `flags`:

> Used with o, x or X specifiers the value is preceded with 0, 0x or 0X
>   respectively for values different than zero. Used with e, E and f, it
>   forces the written output to contain a decimal point even if no digits
>   would follow. By default, if no digits follow, no decimal point is
>   written. Used with g or G the result is the same as with e or E but
>   trailing zeros are not removed.

Comment: The cited part doesn't contain anything about hash. What should this be helpfull for?

Comment: @Zaibis: the cited part is talking about the effects of the `#` flag in the format specifier.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't come up with this answer myself.  I just did a quick Google search and found this:

"Adding a # will cause a '0' to be prepended to an octal number (when using the o conversion specifier), or a 0x to be prepended to a hexadecimal number (when using a x conversion specifier). For most other conversion specifiers, adding a # will simply force the inclusion of a decimal point, even if the number has no fractional part."

You can read more here:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html